# React useState hook delivers inconsistent string value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have prepared [a simple test project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/tree/main/word-search) to demonstrate my problem:

[image: Animated screenshot]

There is a MUI TextField, a thumbs up or down icon and a text string with word description.

The custom [App.jsx](https://github.com/afarber/react-questions/blob/main/word-search/src/App.jsx) is shown below:

```
const DICT = {
  AA: "Rough, cindery lava",
  AB: "An abdominal muscle",
  ABS: "Abdominal muscles",
  ABSQUATULATE: "",
  ABSQUATULATING: "",
  ABY: "Pay the penalty",
};

export default function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [found, setFound] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const key = ev.target.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    setWord(key);

    if (key.length < 2) {
      setDescription("");
      return;
    }

    setFound(DICT.hasOwnProperty(key));
    if (!found) {
      setDescription("The word is not found in the dictionary");
      return;
    }

    setDescription(DICT[key] || "");
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="on">
      <TextField
        id="wordInput"
        label="Enter a word"
        value={word}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <Box>
        {found ? <ThumbUp color="primary" /> : <ThumbDown color="error" />}
      </Box>

      <Box>{description}</Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

As you can see in the animated screenshot above, when a user keeps typing or deleting "A" into the TextField, then the word description found in the `DICT` object is displayed inconsistently and it takes few tries until "Rough, cindery lava" is displayed for "AA".

My problem is probably wide spread among ReactJs newbies like myself. And I think I should use the `prevState` form for a hook, but which one of the 3 and how? I am confused.

**UPDATE:**

Implemented a fix without using a useEffect hook, thank you all for the explaining the root cause to me:

```
export default function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [found, setFound] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const key = ev.target.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    setWord(key);

    // use the key and not word below, because the latter is updated async
    if (key.length < 2) {
      setFound(false);
      setDescription("");
    } else {
      setFound(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(DICT, key));
      setDescription(DICT[key] || "The word is not found in the dictionary");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="on">
      <TextField
        id="wordInput"
        label="Enter a word"
        value={word}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <Box>
        {found ? <ThumbUp color="primary" /> : <ThumbDown color="error" />}
      </Box>

      <Box>{description}</Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)  Specifically, note where you call `setFound` and then immediately use the value of `found`, which won't be updated yet at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `setKey()` the value isn't updated until the next render, so you can't access that value (consistently) within the function.

useEffect is designed to respond to changes in state:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (key.length < 2) {
      setDescription("");
      return;
    }

    setDescription(DICT[key] || "");
}, [key]);     // this will run whenever key changes
```

and another to respond to those changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // this will run whenever description changes
  // note: you could just use DICT.hasOwnProperty in the previous useEffect
  // but you can't use "description" in the previous useEffect
  // because it wasn't set during the useEffect

  setFound(!!description);
}, [description]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use UseEffect.

setFound() and setDescription() functions change the value of 'found' and 'description' but it takes it's own running time.
So it needs delays.
But JavaScript compiler doesn't wait until each command finish.
So next commands run before the values of 'found' and 'description' (in JavaScript you can use 'await' to avoid delay errors).
But here, we can fix the error with 'useEffect'.
Here is the correct code.

```js
const DICT = {
  AA: "Rough, cindery lava",
  AB: "An abdominal muscle",
  ABS: "Abdominal muscles",
  ABSQUATULATE: "",
  ABSQUATULATING: "",
  ABY: "Pay the penalty",
  ALM: "Alarm"
};


export default function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [found, setFound] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(DICT.hasOwnProperty(word));
    const found = DICT.hasOwnProperty(word);
    setFound(found);
    if (!found) {
      console.log("not Found!");
      setDescription(word.length < 2 ? "" : "The word is not found in the dictionary");
      return;
    }

    setDescription(DICT[word] || "");
  }, [word]);


  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const key = ev.target.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    setWord(key);
    
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="on">
      <TextField
        id="wordInput"
        label="Enter a word"
        value={word}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <Box>
        {found ? <ThumbUp color="primary" /> : <ThumbDown color="error" />}
      </Box>

      <Box>{description}</Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Please try to insert this code in your project.
I think it will work correctly...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this code:

```
setFound(DICT.hasOwnProperty(key));
if (!found) {
  setDescription("The word is not found in the dictionary");
  return;
}
```

remember: the useState hook is not synchronous. So, you cannot validate the value just after setting it.

you need to use the useEffect hook in order to listen to the state change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    const newDescription = found ? DICT[word] || "" : "The word is not found in the dictionary"
    setDescription(newDescription)
    

}, [found])
```

but I think it is not necessary to use the found State, just the description state. Like this:

```
const handleChange = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const key = ev.target.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    setWord(key);

    if (key.length < 2) {
      setDescription("");
      return;
    }

    setDescription(DICT[key] || The word is not found in the dictionary");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The state inside `handleChange` is the current state when called. All state updates would affect the next invocation of `handleChange`. This means that when you do this:

```
setFound(DICT.hasOwnProperty(key));
if (!found) {
  setDescription("The word is not found in the dictionary");
  return;
}
```

The `found` state you're using is one step behind. The value would only update after the render caused by setting the state.

The rookie mistake you're making is having a state for computed values. Computed values are derived out of the current state, and don't need a state of their own. You can compute the value of `found` and `description` on each render, and store them in a `const` instead. This would reduce the need for redundant `useEffect` calls that update other states, that cause multiple unnecessary re-renders, and make it harder to trace the flow.

If the computation is resource heavy, and the component might render because of unrelated changes, you can use `useMemo` or memoize the component to avoid unnecessary calculations. In your case, the cost of computing both `found` and `description` is negligible.

**Example (see comments in code):**

```
// derive the value of description from the combination of word and found
function getDescription(word, found) {
  if(word.length < 2) return "";

  return found
    ? DICT[word]
    : "The word is not found in the dictionary";
}

export default function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  
  const found = DICT.hasOwnProperty(word); // compute found
  const description = getDescription(word, found); // compute description

  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const key = ev.target.value.trim().toUpperCase();
    setWord(key);
  };
  
  // the rest of the component's code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is bad, because found is not update immediately after you call setFound(...)

```
setFound(DICT.hasOwnProperty(key));
if (!found) {
  setDescription("The word is not found in the dictionary");
  return;
}
```

should be

```
const newFoundValue = DICT.hasOwnProperty(key)
setFound(newFoundValue);
if (!newFoundValue) {
  setDescription("The word is not found in the dictionary");
  return;
}
```

Also, You don't need to create state for `found` and `description`, use `useMemo` for that (because they can be computed or derived from the input value). If you have firstname and lastname state, you don't need a state called fullname, you can just compute fullname from firstname and lastname